# Can an Azure App Service be tied to a client's external Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We have written some code (I hesitate to use the term "application") in .NET Core using Visual Studio 2019.  This concept is relatively simple; when a user opens a "proprietary" Excel workbook (an Excel file that calls our code) the code goes out to a hosted (by us) Azure SQL Managed database and returns data based on the parameters passed in by the user.

In Azure, we have a single production App Service plan with an App Service dedicated to each client (company).  My question is about security: I'd like to tie each App Service to the related company's Azure AD.  I do NOT want to create an account on my Azure AD for each user, although I can certainly do this through the "invitation" process using B2B.  Can each App Service be "pointed" to a specific external instance of Azure AD so that only users from that company can access the related data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use two different flows:

- Each WebApp will authenticate users from only one specific Azure AD tenant
- One WebApp will authenticate users from multiple Azure AD tenants

Both solution can be achieved with Azure AD multi-tenant authentication application pattern.

Here are steps you need to implement:

- Update App registration to be multi-tenant
- Update your code to send requests to /common
- Update your code to handle multiple/single issuer values

Here is a picture that describes the flow

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: Great, thank you.  I read about this process and wasn't sure if it applied to our "application".  Thank you for the direction.  Much appreciated.